# Blank white lines in eps exported surf plots

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, export, eps

I exported a surf plot in eps format using the below code.

```
  s = figure(10); 
  surfc(double(smooth_img));
  saveas(figure(10), 'surf.eps','epsc2');
```

[image]

I'm not able to remove the blank white lines in the image (i.e. at y = 250 and x =100). Does anybody have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can have tons of reasons. Here are some suggestions for trouble shooting:

1) Use [**`print`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html) instead of `saveas`. There is no difference for vector-graphics, assuming you actually set the renderer to `painters`.

```
set(gcf,'Renderer','painters')
print(gcf,'surf.eps','-depsc2')
```

2) What about other formats? Have you tried using `svg` and `eps`? Does the error remain?